# Change C++ target application to XP

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

I built a **C++** application with **Microsoft Visual Studio 2012**, but when tried it in **Windows XP**, it returns "**not valid win 32 application**".

I found some similar questions in stackoverflow and the msdn blog, and all of them say to change the **toolkit plateform to XP**, but in my case i didn't find this option.

I tried to make an update to the ** C++ redistrubitable** , but this doesn't solve the issue.

Does anyone have an idea about the problem?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps, you compiled it as x64. Try to find that option and change it to x86.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your app using windows xp targeting tool set. You can download it [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-visual-studio-2012-update). More info on [msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

The [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx) website offers a great description of creating and modifying Win32 Applications.

They even offer a video that gives you a step by step on creating such a thing and any other questions you may have regarding Win32 applications.

Also, you can download and build your application using [Windows XP Targeting Tool Set](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-visual-studio-2012-update).